# I can run my .jmx file using GUI mode but can't using non-gui mode. I am running command "jmeter -n -t Peda_First.jmx -l testresult.jtl" in terminal

Tags: jmeter

Getting below error while running through terminal(non-gui mode).

Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML

Please see [txt.do/1ayhc](https://txt.do/1ayhc) this link for jmeter.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you're trying to run JMeter script created with later JMeter version (most probably [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)) with an older JMeter version (most probably [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/four-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213)). I doubt that it is something you really want.

Most probably you have JMeter 2.13 installed via your Linux distribution [package manager](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-package-management/) so I would recommend using the full path to JMeter 5.0 instead of relying onto your operating system [PATH environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), to wit instead of running your test as

```
jmeter -n -t Peda_First.jmx -l testresult.jtl
```

run it like:

```
/home/vimal/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/./jmeter -n -t Peda_First.jmx -l testresult.jtl
```

You can also consider adding the next lines to your [bash_profile file](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/)

```
PATH=/home/vimal/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

this will make the changes permanent and you will be launching JMeter 5.0 by typing `jmeter` in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old version of JMeter to load a more recent jmx file.

2.13 version is very old, last version is 5.0 as of February 2019.

You can download JMeter from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).
Install JDK 8 before and use it to run jmeter.

Comment: Yes, Please could let me know how can I update my non-GUI jmeter version. FYI I am using 5.0 as jmeter GUI version. But I'm trying to running my .jmx file using terminal with command jmeter -n -t Peda_First.jmx -l testresult.jtl